# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2 dialog box (select folder/path) very slow response

Tags: intellij-idea

I have recently started to use IDEA (Community Edition) instead of my favourite Eclipse. I like it so far. But there is one thing that is really annoying - when I need to select a path for file a new dialog box appears and I need to wait something like 1 MINUTE until I can select a folder from the tree. It looks like IDE is reading whole folder structure everytime dialog appears. Is there a setup that could speed up the process?

Comment: It looks like a native hardware slowness issue since I have the Ultimate Edition (with plenty of plugins in) on my 6GB RAM Ubuntu box just working in perfect charm.

Comment: It happens to me when I have a network drive, but I am not on the network, but the same thing happens while opening "This Computer". If it blocks the GUI, then you will find stacktraces in log folder and you can see what is the problem.

Comment: Is there any setup that could disable this tree view and just ask for the path?

Comment: I do not have any other issues, "This Computer" works fine :) Only the IDEA is slow with the folder structure. Why, oh why....